# Adding custom HTTP Headers to all web application in IIS Manager 6

Tags: c#, iis, http-headers, windows-server-2003

I need to add x-frame http headers to all web application in a IIS Manager 6 but not sure how I can do it.

Can someone point me to right direction as I don't want to do it manually for 400 web applications and also ServerManager doesn't work as its not IIS 7.

Also if you know any freeware utility I can use for this task please ?

Comment: You could use PowerShell

Comment: Deemac thanks i would but its server 2003 :(

Comment: "These values can be set globally for all sites or separately within each site. Internet Information Services (IIS) uses an inheritance model for these settings." That sounds hopeful. Look at this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732442.aspx

Comment: Yes but then I have to do it for 400 IIS web applications